# How to calculate: $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{(3n+i-1)(3n+i)}$.

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

While solving a question that has to do with Darboux sums I reached the following sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{(3n+i-1)(3n+i)}$$

and I didn't know how to do it. but I know its supposed to be $\frac{1}{12}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : Consider $$\frac{n}{3n+i-1}-\frac{n}{3n+i}=\frac{n}{(3n+i-1)(3n+i)}$$

The only terms which do not cancel out are $\frac{n}{3n+i-1}$ for $i=1$ 
and $\frac{n}{3n+i}$ for $i=n$ giving $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: did that, and calculated the integral of each one seperately, at the end i got $nln(\frac{12n^2}{12n^2-a+1})$ .. but thats not a number!

Comment: The trick is to cancel out equal terms.

Comment: And the surprising result is that the sum has the same value, independent from $n$, so the limit has also this value.

Comment: WOW! didn't think of this! thanks alot fot the magic!

Comment: I did not have the idea either, when I met such a series for the first time ...

Answer (score 3):

Since one of the tag's is "Riemann Sum," I assume that the problem is to find

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{1}^n\frac{n}{(3n+i)(3n+i-1)}$$

by interpreting the sum as a Riemann sum.  To that end, we write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{1}^n\frac{n}{(3n+i)(3n+i-1)}&=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{1}^n\frac{1}{(3+i/n)(3+(i-1)/n)}\left(\frac1n\right)\\\\
&= \int_0^1\frac{1}{(3+x)^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\left.\left(-\frac{1}{3x+1}\right)\right|_0^1\\\\
&=\frac1{12}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: I didn't understand the third line , where the arrow appears, how did u move to this point ?

Comment: @F1sargyan This is the Riemann Sum.  As $n\to \infty$ the sum approaches the integral.

Answer (score 2):

Telescopic series
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{n}{(3n+i-1)(3n+i)}
\sum_{i=1}^n=\frac{1-i}{3 (i+3 n-1)}+\frac{i}{3 (i+3 n)}=
\left(\frac{0}{3 (3 n)}+\frac{1}{3 (1+3 n)} \right)+
\left(\frac{-1}{3 (1+3 n)}+\frac{2}{3 (2+3 n)}\right)+
\left(\frac{-2}{3 (2+3 n)}+\frac{3}{3 (3+3 n)}\right)+
\left(\frac{-3}{3 (3+3 n)}+\frac{4}{3 (4+3 n)}\right)\dots=
\left( \frac{n}{3(4n)}\right)=\frac{1}{12}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice, the partial fractions $$\frac{n}{(3n+i-1)(3n+i)}=\frac{n}{3n+i-1}-\frac{n}{3n+i}$$

Now, we have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n}{(3n+i-1)(3n+i)}$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{n}{3n+i-1}-\frac{n}{3n+i}\right)$$
$$=n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{3n+i-1}-\frac{1}{3n+i}\right)$$
$$=n\left(\left(\frac{1}{3n}-\frac{1}{3n+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{3n+2}\right)+\ldots +\left(\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n}\right)\right)$$
$$=n\left(\frac{1}{3n}-\frac{1}{4n}\right)$$
$$=n\left(\frac{1}{12n}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{12}}$$